# laravel-vite-plugin not working when using monorepo

Tags: laravel, vite

laravel-vite-plugin not working when using monorepo

```
{{Vite::useBuildDirectory('build/cms')->withEntryPoints(['../cms/src/main.ts'])}}

GET http://[::1]:5173/cms/src/main.ts net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When run dev then cannot find main.ts. It only working with run build

I using monorepo but Cannot setup vite can read path main.ts

Help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You ahven't provided anywhere near enough information. It would be great if you could post your directory structures, where the key files are found (package.json, main.ts, your vite.config.ts.etc.)

Without this unfortunately, we cannot help you. If you can provide that inforamtion, we can give it a crack :)